# Python function - why is it called twice?

Tags: python-3.x

In the following Code the function g() is called twice, but why? Is it because in function f() that x=g and than function x() is called but in fact it is g()?

```
x = 99

def f():
    x = g
    x()
    x = 17

def g():
    global x 
    x = 14

g()
f()
```

Comment: `Is it because in function f() that x=g and than function x() is called but in fact it is g()?` Yep.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this by simply adding a `print` statement as in the following:

```
x = 99

def f():
  x = g
  print(x)
  x()
  x = 17

def g():
  global x
  x = 14

g()
f()
```

Output would be: `<function g at 0x7f2147265c80>` which shows that printing `x` in line 4 is indeed calling the function `g()`